# get values of particular key in nsdictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I saved the `json` parsing result in a `dictionary` which look like:

```
{
 "statusCode":"200",
"body":[
  {
     "status":"success",
     "remarks":null
  }
],

"data":[
     "abcd":[
        {
           "category":"a",
           "title":"b",
           "id":"24"
        },
        {
           "category":"c",
           "title":"crd",
           "id":"65"
        },
        {
           "category":"ds",
           "title":"sd",
           "id":"18"
        }

     ]
  },
  {
     "efgh":[
        {
           "category":"ds",
           "title":"sd",
           "id":"18"
        },
        {
           "category":"sd",
           "title":"sd",
           "id":"1"
        }

                             ]
  },
  {
     "ijkl":[
        {
           "category":"ds",
           "title":"sd",
           "id":"18"
        },
        {
           "category":"sd",
           "title":"sd",
           "id":"1"
        }

     ]
  }
 ]
}
```

The data for key @"data" can be saved into an array by using

```
NSMutableArray *getdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
getcat=[results objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Now what should I do for the `values(category, title, id)` inside the first index i.e. `"abcd"`.

If anyone has any knowledge please look upon that.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Following will give you the desired object

```
NSDictionary *dict=[results valueForKeyPath:@"data.abcd"][0];
```

For individual:

```
NSString *categoryString=[[results valueForKeyPath:@"data.abcd"][0] objectForKey:@"Category"];
NSString *idString=[[results valueForKeyPath:@"data.abcd"][0] objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *titleString=[[results valueForKeyPath:@"data.abcd"][0] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Also,

```
NSString *categoryString=dict[@"Category"];
NSString *idString=dict[@"id"];
NSString *titleString=dict[@"title"];
```

Comment: I am unable to get the value inside the dictionary i.e. category, id, title.

Comment: nslog dict, as shown in my answer, and tell what gets printed.

Comment: I got the inside key values by                      NSString *cat=[dict valueForKeyPath:@"id"][0];
 It means to get all the id for a particular keys for example all the ids under "abcd" I have to use for loop.

Comment: How to get the "abcd" key name from data?  Because i want to show "abcd" as  my tableview section title. in my case "abcd" and "efgh" is dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

Check like this:

```
NSString *value=[[[getcate valueForKey:@"abcd"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"category"];
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an array so use `objectAtIndex:` (i.e. `[getcat objectAtIndex:0]` or `getcat[0]`)

Comment: Yes I done this already..                                   NSMutableArray *firstarray=[getcat objectAtIndex:0];                    "abcd":[
        {
           "category":"a",
           "title":"b",
           "id":"24"
        },
        {
           "category":"c",
           "title":"crd",
           "id":"65"
        },
        {
           "category":"ds",
           "title":"sd",
           "id":"18"
        }

     ]  But now how to get value inside the abcd i.e. category, title, id

Comment: That's another Dictionary.  I don't understand why this gives so many people so much trouble.  You already did the exact same thing in this line -> `getcat=[results objectForKey:@"data"];` so just do it again.  JSON is not rocket science.  You can only get about 5 or 6 different types out, and only **two** collection types.  So collections are either arrays (get by number) or dictionaries (get by string).