# iOS AFNetworking post troubles

Tags: ios, post, afnetworking

I am currently trying to post to a php web service which will query a mysql database and [should] return with a string value. I have looked into AFNetworking but do not understand how to use the value which is returned from the query. for example:

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"http://samwize.com/api/poo/"
parameters:@{@"color": @"green"}
  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I am guessing I manipulate responseObject to get my expected string? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [manager POST:@"http://samwize.com/api/poo/"
           parameters:@{@"color": @"green"}
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                  NSError *error = nil;
                  NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"Error serializing %@", error);
                  }
                  NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON);
              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
              }];
```

This will convert your `JSON` response to `NSDictionary`

Comment: Thank you.  And how can i return a value from a given key using nsdictionary

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question right, do you want the value from a key? take a look at this answer if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233425/get-values-of-particular-key-in-nsdictionary