# JSON object data to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

How can I populate a few UILabels on a ViewController from the JSON object I receive from a previously passed id parameter? I get the response from the server but, I don't know how to populate the key/value pairs to a UILabel.

The JSON response I get is:

```
{
    product =     {
        attributes =         (
        );
        "average_rating" = "0.00";
        backordered = 0;
        "backorders_allowed" = 0;
        "button_text" = "";
        "catalog_visibility" = visible;
        categories =         (
        );
        "created_at" = "2016-02-23T05:00:55Z";
        "cross_sell_ids" =         (
        );
        description = "<p>Microsoft Office</p>\n";
        dimensions =         {
            height = "";
            length = "";
            unit = in;
            width = "";
        };
        "download_expiry" = 0;
        "download_limit" = 0;
        "download_type" = "";
        downloadable = 0;
        downloads =         (
        );
        featured = 0;
        "featured_src" = "https://qashop.taxometry.com/wordpressv4/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/softwarecontract-150x150.jpg";
        "grouped_products" =         (
        );
        id = 15;
        images =         (
                        {
                alt = "";
                "created_at" = "2016-02-23T05:01:35Z";
                id = 16;
                position = 0;
                src = "https://qashop.taxometry.com/wordpressv4/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/softwarecontract-150x150.jpg";
                title = "softwarecontract-150&#215;150";
                "updated_at" = "2016-02-23T05:01:35Z";
            }
        );
        "in_stock" = 1;
        "managing_stock" = 0;
        "menu_order" = 0;
        "on_sale" = 1;
        parent =         (
        );
        "parent_id" = 0;
        permalink = "https://qashop.taxometry.com/wordpressv4/product/software-contract/";
        price = 25;
        "price_html" = "<del><span class=\"amount\">&#36;30.00</span></del> <ins><span class=\"amount\">&#36;25.00</span></ins>";
        "product_url" = "";
        "purchase_note" = "";
        purchaseable = 1;
        "rating_count" = 0;
        "regular_price" = 30;
        "related_ids" =         (
        );
        "reviews_allowed" = 1;
        "sale_price" = 25;
        "shipping_class" = "";
        "shipping_class_id" = "<null>";
        "shipping_required" = 1;
        "shipping_taxable" = 1;
        "short_description" = "";
        sku = 2370;
        "sold_individually" = 0;
        status = publish;
        "stock_quantity" = "<null>";
        tags =         (
        );
        "tax_class" = "";
        "tax_status" = taxable;
        taxable = 1;
        title = "Software Contract";
        "total_sales" = 5;
        type = simple;
        "updated_at" = "2016-02-23T05:01:41Z";
        "upsell_ids" =         (
        );
        variations =         (
        );
        virtual = 0;
        visible = 1;
        weight = "<null>";
    };
}
```

Comment: Why don't you Google and start from scratch ? Store response in NSDictionary and use it !

Comment: What value do you want to populate to your  Label?

Comment: Google how to put json into an NSDictionary, then google how to get a value from NSDictionary for a specific key. Assign it to your label. If you want the exact answer then show us some code or tell us the exact key against which you require your value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - > [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233425/get-values-of-particular-key-in-nsdictionary)

then [Second](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_labels.htm)